# Failed to install libmysql++-dev on debian

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I tried to install libmysql++-dev package on my machine but failed with below errors. I already done apt-get update and apt-get update on the machine.

```
22:28:03-root@debian-isis-> apt-get  install libmysql++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.74) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
               Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.104) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
               Breaks: nfs-common (< 1:1.2.5-3) but 1:1.2.2-4squeeze2 is to be installed
 keyboard-configuration : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.71) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
 klibc-utils : Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.103) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
 libgnome-keyring0 : Breaks: gnome-keyring (< 3.0) but 2.30.3-5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Your system has been incompletely upgraded between releases. Fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing using aptitude instead of apt-get.